# Facebook profile pic URL redirect to different URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Faceboook API to login into my website through FB.

In this when I try to fetch the profile photo of the logged-in user through URL "http://graph.facebook.com/100003373201743/picture". Didn't get the response in code.

*id of user fetched from FB @ run time.

Found the reason as well, coz defined URL redirects to "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-frc3/t1.0-1/p50x50/1975108_483512481771188_559759638979699650_s.jpg". I am not  finding any link between these two URLs. So that I can directly hit to redirected one URL.

Comment: Why don't you use the "http://graph.facebook.com/100003373201743/picture" in the src attribute of your image tag?

Comment: _“I am not finding any link between these two URLs”_ – well you’re simply wrong in assuming there _is_ one. What kind of URLs FB uses on their CDNs and how the build them, is completely up to them (and might change over time).

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the image url as "http://graph.facebook.com/100003373201743/picture", as @Tobi has mentioned

or,

if you want to fetch the actual url, you can get that in response of this-

```
http://graph.facebook.com/100003373201743/picture?redirect=0
```

You'll get the response as-

```
{
   data: {
     url: "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-frc3/t1.0-1/p50x50/1975108_483512481771188_559759638979699650_s.jpg",
     is_silhouette: false
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually I need to save this image. which is not possible with  http://graph.facebook.com/100003373201743/picture

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this problem.

Fetching headers of the URL "http://graph.facebook.com/100003373201743/picture".

Header named as "Location" have the value of redirected URL like "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-frc3/t1.0-1/p50x50/1975108_483512481771188_559759638979699650_s.jpg"

So hitting this URL and its working fine.

Comment: It seems that the images are downloaded instead of being showed in the browser.